# Python instance deletion

Tags: python, memory-leaks, instance

I'm new to programming and I can't understand how garbage collection works.  In the following example:

```
import Tkinter as tk

a = 0

class Object1:

    def __init__(self):
        global a
        a = tk.Frame()
        a.pack()
        b = tk.Button(a, text="click me", command=self.callback)
        b.pack()

    def callback(self):
        print "clicked!"
        program = Object2()

class Object2:

    def __init__(self):
        global a
        a.destroy()
        a2 = tk.Frame()
        a2.pack()
        b = tk.Label(a2, text='This is the second object.')
        b.pack()



program = Object1()

tk.mainloop()
```

Does 'program,' the instance of Object1, remain at the end?  Do I have to explicitly delete it somehow?  If I repeat this structure many times, with each Objectx having a button that destroys the previous frame and adds a new frame with new content, will that consume more and more memory as the program proceeds?  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a` will reference a "destroyed" `tk.Frame`

To allow the `tk.Frame` to be garbage collected you need to remove that reference to it

One way is to set `a = None` another way would be to `del a`

Of course when the program actually ends *everything* is freed

Answer (score 0):

So... if you're new to programming you definitely do not need to even be thinking about garbage collection.

First, you need to know how variable scopes work in Python.  Basic - variables declared in a certain block (tab level) do not leave that block.  Module global variables are those defined at the first tab level (such as a in your example).  True global variables that will be accessible between modules (files) need to be declared as such.  There's more to it than that - but don't get carried away.  Read the link at the end of this post for more detailed info.

Second, you're starting to fall into a pattern of premature optimization.  Have you experienced excessive memory usage that's causing you problems?  If so, then and only then, you need to figure out a way to isolate variable scope (for instance inside a for loop body for each iteration).  Just get the code to do what you want before you start worrying about performance, then only spend time changing things that have a big impact on speed (the biggest loops that run the most) or memory (wasteful variable usage).

Third, garbage collection isn't relevant semantically, variable scope is.  Python isn't great at managing memory, that's just how it is.  For instance, a dictionary object will not reduce in size, even if you fill it and then manage to delete all the items; furthermore, when the dictionary container needs to grow, it only doubles (i.e. 500M-->1G-->2G).  But don't let that scare you - it rarely is actually an issue.

Check out [SaltyCrane's blog](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/python-variable-scope-notes/) on variable scope.